# My setState throws errors and I dont know how to go about it

Tags: reactjs, components, setstate

I tried to set state in the render and it throws 'Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.' i the console.

**My code**

```
    class All extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { products: {} };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCategories();
        this.props.fetchProducts();
      }

      render() {
        this.setState({ products: this.props.products });
        const { products } = this.state;
        console.log(this.props.products);
        return (
          <div>
            { !products.length
              ? (
                <div className="ring">
                  Loading
                  <span />
                </div>
              )
              : (
                <ProductTemplate />
              ) }
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

**The Error**

[image: The Error i got]

Whenever I comment it out, the code runs without error but the state is still empty

Comment: As the error points out, you shouldn't call the `setState` in the render ......

Comment: Yeah, where can I call it? I tried to create a function and set the state in the function but I will still need to call the function somewhere and I will still be in the render so I have problem in that aspect.

Comment: I don't see why you require a `setState` here at all .... I would just replace `products` with `this.props.products` in the current code ...

Comment: Thank you, I have put aside local state and I have used the global state.